# Composer Memory Limit

Tags: composer-php

I installed composer global at a Webhosting-Server. 
Now I can call it via

```
composer
```

But if I want to install something I get a memory limit error. 
Now I want to call it with

```
php -d memory_limit=1024M composer.phar
```

but it doesn't work. Probably because I installed it globaly. 
How can I get a extended memory_limit with composer via shell?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

When calling Composer binary by using `php` CLI directly, you need to provide the full path to the Composer phar, e.g., if it were installed in `/usr/local/bin`, you would call it with:

```
php -d memory_limit=1024M /usr/local/bin/composer.phar
```

Comment: Thank you. But the full path don't work if you set a alias for composer at least for me.

Comment: Why don't you set the alis for composer with the full path? `alias composer='php -d memory_limit=1024M /usr/local/bin/composer.phar'`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had a VM and increasing the memory lmit of my VM solved my problem

Answer (score -1):

```
alias composer='php -d memory_limit=1024M -d suhosin.executor.include.whitelist=phar,http://,https:// /is/htdocs/xxxxxx_xxxxx/script/composer/composer.phar'
```

Worked for me

I use an alias for composer so I don't need to call the whole path if I want to use composer. But with this alias I am not able to call composer via "composer.phar". So I added the memory limit command to the alias function which worked for me.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for posting what worked for you. Can you add something about why this works, or what led you to try it? That'd make the answer more useful to others, and perhaps it'll be a reminder for you in the future. Thanks!

Comment: I found the solution in a help documentation from my hoster.