# How to solve memory limit and composer errors in Laravel project?

Tags: php, laravel, memory, composer-php, limit

When I run the Laravel project via **php artisan serve** I get an error about **/vendor/autoload.php** as no such file or directiory in **/artisan**. Then after I did couple of research I found that composer does not exist. Hence, I tried to update composer via **composer update** I get an error about the memory limit as such:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1610612736 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 67108864 bytes) in phar:///usr/local/Cellar/composer/1.10.7/bin/composer/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Solver.php on line 223

And then I try to increase the memory  to make the memory infinite with the command **php -d memory_limit=-1** but then, terminal is not giving me a response.
I cloned the project through **git** and there is no **.env** file in my project. How can I solve the problem?

When I run **composer install** I get the errors below.

> Problem 1
> - Installation request for laravel/horizon v4.3.3 -> satisfiable by laravel/horizon[v4.3.3].
> - laravel/horizon v4.3.3 requires ext-pcntl * -> the requested PHP extension pcntl is missing from your system.

> Problem 2
> - Installation request for phpoffice/phpspreadsheet 1.13.0 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.13.0].
> - phpoffice/phpspreadsheet 1.13.0 requires ext-zip * -> the requested PHP extension zip is missing from your system.

> Problem 3
> - phpoffice/phpspreadsheet 1.13.0 requires ext-zip * -> the requested PHP extension zip is missing from your system.
> - maatwebsite/excel 3.1.19 requires phpoffice/phpspreadsheet ^1.10 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.13.0].
> - Installation request for maatwebsite/excel 3.1.19 -> satisfiable by maatwebsite/excel[3.1.19].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Composer Memory Limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49539512/composer-memory-limit)

Comment: Additionally, please do not randomly run `composer update` - this will change the versions of packages to be installed. Usually, you should run `composer install` unless you know **why** you run `composer update`

Comment: **composer install** does not work too.

Comment: According to the error message you've posted, it's pretty clear why `composer install` does not succeed. Please read them and install and activate the missing extensions

Answer (score 1):

Did you try with the information listed over [here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#memory-limit-errors)

You can also try this command `php -d memory_limit=-1 $(which composer) update`

You may wanna [check](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36107762/5749451) this topic aswell

Also

> I had to combine `COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT` and `memory_limit` in the command line:

On Windows:

```
set COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=99999999999&& php -d memory_limit=-1 composer.phar update
```

On Linux:

```
export COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=99999999999 && php -d memory_limit=-1 composer.phar update
```

Comment: I get an error like **Could not open input file: composer.phar**

Comment: Are you in  the diirectory of the project? you need to hhave composr installed globally

Answer (score -1):

This is the command that solves all problems I mentioned above.

> composer install --ignore-platform-reqs