# Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1610612736 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 83886080 bytes) using composer on go daddy server

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

i am not able to run any command to terminal i have to try many different way. but every time getting error even i can't update composer package on live server.

```
m647gkelg644@sxb1plzcpnl453522 [~]$ cd public_html
m647gkelg644@sxb1plzcpnl453522 [~/public_html]$ composer require intervention/image
Warning from https://repo.packagist.org: Support for Composer 1 is deprecated and some packages will not be available. You should upgrade to Composer 2. See https://blog.packagist.com/deprecating-composer-1-support/
Using version ^2.5 for intervention/image
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Warning from https://repo.packagist.org: Support for Composer 1 is deprecated and some packages will not be available. You should upgrade to Composer 2. See https://blog.packagist.com/deprecating-composer-1-support/
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1610612736 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 83886080 bytes) in phar:///opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleSet.php on line 90

Check https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#memory-limit-errors for more info on how to handle out of memory errors.m647gkelg644@sxb1plzcpnl453522 [~/public_html]$ ^C
m647gkelg644@sxb1plzcpnl453522 [~/public_html]$
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67044276/laravel-cant-install-intevention-image-due-to-out-of-memory/67054887#67054887

Comment: I think you have a low memory machine. Try it again with more memory (ram).

Comment: Please share more details. Why do you run `composer require` on any other system than your local development system? That's discouraged, and that has been explained on SO multiple times. Run `composer require` on your **local** system, where such limits do not apply, and properly deploy your application by only using `composer install`

Comment: I think you should set memory_limit to -1, to install, then set it back to its original value after installing the library.